# What does it mean to restart your session?

Tags: gnome, configuration, restart, session, gnome-control-center

I just went into the `gnome-control-center > Region & Language` and changed the `Formats` section to `Russian Federation`, however now it is tell me to restart the session:

[image]

But what does this mean? Is it the same as logging in and out again? If I click `Restart Now`, will it just log me in and out into a new session? Will all my applications be closed and then I'll be given a new session, or what will happen...? I already tried just restarting GNOME Shell and that didn't work so I assume it's the entire session and there is no way to do this without just restarting the whole thing?

I am asking what it does before doing it just to be sure that I need to close all of my applications before doing it and save all open documents etc.

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: It logs you out, goes back to lightdm and then starts the session again. So yes, you need to close the applications open in the desktop (if you have something running on another tty, it will stay there).

Comment: @dadexix86: It can't go back to lightdm... I am running GNOME so it'll be GDM. I don't have lightdm installed.

Comment: My bad, I'm sorry :) you are right :) It is GDM  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarting your session will kill all of your programs and start your desktop environment again. It's basically logging out and in from your "account". If you do it, all the unsaved work will be lost, so make sure you save everything you're working on.